# Listbox :How to display child dialog based on list box selection?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am developing mfc based vc++ dialog application. In my program I have a one parent dialog say IDD_PARENT and two child dialogs say IDD_PAGE1 and IDD_PAGE2. In IDD_PARENT dialog i have a listbox control with the strings Page 1 and Page 2. When a user clicks Page 1 in list box I need my application to display the dialog IDD_PAGE1 in the IDD_PARENT dialog same for the case with Page 2 also. How can I do it? I am new to the VC++ environment. Examples using code portions will be helping.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you want embedded child dialogs.  Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4408/Creating-embedded-dialogs-in-MFC).